# How can I block a bluetooth profile on Android?

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I have a karaoke App where microphone is on together with speakers. When user connects the same Bluetooth headphone device multiple times, sometimes it connects as A2DP (high audio quality, keeps using builtin microphone of the device), and sometimes as HFD (low quality and bluetooth microphone). Even if I manually change the microphone source, the output audio is still bad. Is there a way of only allowing A2DP profile on an Android app?